# Update content injected via "innerHTML" in Angular

Tags: angular, wordpress, innerhtml, headless, sanitization

I'm working on an application that has the following infrastructure:

- Headless Wordpress used as primary DB
- Node.js application used as middleware/backend
- Angular for the frontend

I'm in a situation where I need to fetch dynamic content from Wordpress (content of type "Page") for a particular section, the News section.

The problem is this: the news abstract can contain internal links to navigate to certain sections of the website.

This content, once arrived at the frontend, is injected through the "innerHTML" property into a div.

Now, I can't add the "routerLink" property directly on the HTML coming from Wordpress, because Angular sanitizes it.

At the same time, I don't want to remove sanitization process to avoid security issues.

I tried adding the "routerLink" property directly on the frontend, through ViewChild, but the content injected via "innerHTML" seems inert and not susceptible to updates.

Is there any way to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: do you have an example of the html coming back from wordpress?

Comment: So you would like to catch click on `<a href="/something">` inside innerHTML content, and do `router.navigate(['/something'])`?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a `(click)` event to the element you're rendering the `[innterHTML]` to and trap the event and navigate to where it is supposed to go.

```
<div [innterHTML]="data" (click)="elementClicked($event)"></div>
```

---

```
elementClicked($event: any) {
    $event.stopPropagation();
    const target = $event.target || $event.srcElement || $event.currentTarget;

    if (!target) return;
    
    const href = target.attributes.href;

    if (!href) return;
    // if the url is meant to navigate within the app...
    this.router.navigateByUrl(href);
}
```